# Maven test in Eclipse fails, but the same test in Jenkins succeded

Tags: eclipse, maven, jenkins

This is my code:

```
package example;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.AssertJUnit;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.AssertJUnit;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.AssertJUnit;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;

public class NewTest {

private WebDriver driver;

@Test
public void f() {

    driver.get("http://demo.guru99.com/selenium/guru99home/");  
    String title = driver.getTitle();                
    AssertJUnit.assertTrue(title.contains("Demo Guru99 Pageee"));

    System.out.println("Success");
}

@BeforeTest
public void beforeTest() {
  String exePath = "/Users/enislavmollov/Downloads/chromedriver";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", exePath);
  driver = new ChromeDriver();


}

@AfterTest
public void afterTest() {
  driver.quit();
}

}
```

When I run my test in eclipse it fails(I did it on purpose)
[image: Eclipse test]

But when I run it in Jenkins it says Build success
[image: Jenkins build]

How is that possible and how to make Jenkins to give the correct result as the one in Eclipse

Comment: And the actual test is?

Comment: Please see my code above, I just added it.

Comment: I would suggest looking more at what `driver.get()` returns.

Comment: But how is this connect with successful build that Jenkins provide?

Comment: Looks like a result of running on different machines.

Comment: I was wrong.  The problem is that the surefier plugin does not pick up the test.

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse emulation of the Maven model is not 100% correct.

Notably Eclipse does not differentiate between src/main/java and src/test/java - it all goes together in the big pot.  Maven does.

Test classes *must* be placed in src/test/java to be invoked by maven-surefire-plugin.

Comment: Please make a MCVE demonstrating this behavior, and put it on e.g. github.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve